# `Invalid Host header` response from apache2 only over HTTP

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, http

When I perform a cURL request on my apache2 server via HTTP, the only response I receive is `Invalid Host header`. However, when using HTTPS, everything seems to work as expected. I do have rewrite enabled for each site to redirect to HTTPS. This occurs throughout all subdomains. While I've done some digging, all that I can find are webpack related issues.

I am running `apache2 2.4.52` on `ubuntu 22.04 LTS`.

Here is my main page's conf file.

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias a.example.com
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `cURL --head --verbose http://example.com`

```
*   Trying <my-ip>:80...
* Connected to example.com (my-ip) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 9
Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Sun, 24 Jul 2022 16:09:03 GMT
Date: Sun, 24 Jul 2022 16:09:03 GMT

<
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `curl --head --verbose http://your_server`.

Comment: @DanielB I have added it above.

Comment: So, not an _Invalid Host header_ response. Indeed, there is no such error in Apache Httpd at all. You should investigate using logs where the error comes from and under which conditions it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting a bit. I figured out that it was a port forwarding error  because it was resolving correctly locally but not from the domain.